# Raleigh Circa 2 Mens 2017 Hybrid Bike

Tags: hybrid-bike

Raleigh Circa 2 Mens 2017 Hybrid Bike What are the exact dimensions (in mm) of seat tube and top tube of 16'' frame of this model (CR216MBK)?

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find was [Raleigh's own web site](http://www.raleigh.co.uk/ProductType/ProductRange/Product/Default.aspx?pc=1&pt=266&pg=17790) , and all they list is frame sizes and approximate leg lengths to suit.

If the supplier themselves don't list it, then you'll have to go measure one at a shop, or hope someone else here happens to own one and a tape measure.